# Prove x-coordinate of circumcenter of triangle ABC is ((x1 sin⁡2A+x2 sin⁡2B+x3 sin⁡2C)/(sin⁡2A+sin⁡2B+sin⁡2C )

Tags: coordinate-systems

[image: Finding the coordinates of cercumcenter of triangle ABC in terms of sine of vertexes of triangle]
In the given figure I am not able to proceed further to arrive at the proof. Please do help me to solve this.

Comment: Given that you have the coordinates, it is easier to verify that O lies on the perpendicular bisector of BC.

Comment: Sir finding coordinates of circumcenter is very easy but main question where problem is being faced is to prove coordinates of circum center is [(x1sin 2A + x2sin 2B+ X3sin 2C)/(sin2A+sin2B+sin2C), (y1sin 2A + y2sin 2B+ y3sin 2C)/(sin2A+sin2B+sin2C)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct solution;
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iq50.png]

GS Negi